upload file to sharepoint using Express.js but got "Unsupported app only token" error
I try to make upload files function through Azure to SharePoint in Express.js.
I got the token right(I think) from Azure AD, but when I try to upload files to SharePoint
I keeping got "Unsupported app only token". I don't know is the API permission setting wrong or where could be.
Hope someone can help me out! Thank you!!!!
This is how I got the token and try to use when I call upload files in API
async function getAccessToken() {
    const tokenEndpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
  
    const requestBody = new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: clientSecret,
      scope: `${resource}/.default`
    });
  
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, requestBody, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
          });
          
          return response.data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error obtaining token:', error.response.data);
      throw new Error('Failed to obtain access token');
    }
  }

Here is I try to upload files to SharePoint but got error
async function uploadFileToSharePoint(filePath, fileName, folderPath) {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(); // Get the access token
    const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath); // Read the file from disk

    try {
        const response = await axios.put(
            `${siteUrl}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(${folderPath})/Files/add(url=${fileName},overwrite=true)`,
            file,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
                }
            }
        );

        return response.data.d; // Return the response data from SharePoint
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading to SharePoint:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        throw new Error('File upload to SharePoint failed.');
    }
}

Here is my error "Error uploading to SharePoint: Unsupported app only token."
My expecting is can upload files to SharePoint successfully

If you are making use of client credential flow that make use of certificate to authenticate not client secret

check this https://gist.github.com/phillipharding/d6cc4b84221cf5304e41d97beb62ea6c


Note that: Generating access token for SharePoint using client credential flow only accepts access tokens requested with a client certificate, not a client secret. Refer this MsDoc

Hence you have to either make use of user interactive flow or use Microsoft Graph API which supports client credential flow which supports secrets.

Hence pass certificate instead of secret to generate access token refer this blog by Martin Loitzl

Use the below endpoint to authorize users:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://Domain.sharepoint.com/.default
&state=12345



Generate access token by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://Domain.sharepoint.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms



Otherwise, make use of Microsoft Graph API. Refer this MsDoc
Reference:
Tutorial: Sign in users in a Node.js & Express web app - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft
